# No inodes information in `du -i`

Tags: filesystems, inode

Although `df` reports there is still plenty of space, I encountered 'No space left on device' problem while running processes that tend to create loads of small files. I thought it might be a problem of inodes availability.

Nevertheless, `df -i` shows:

```
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1            0     0       0     - /home
```

How shall I interpret these zeros? Is it already an indication of a problem? How do I know if it was an inode problem?

The system is Ubuntu 14.04 (it's not me who administers this...) and the filesystem is btrfs.

Answer (score 1):

Btrfs doesn't use inodes in the way `du` thinks filesystems work.

Simple as that; the concept "inode" doesn't apply to btrfs.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, just found this info. Any idea then how to deal with a potential problem of too many files on this filesystem?

Comment: it doesn't say "too many files", it says "no space left on device!" You might be running out of some direntries; but your `dmesg` our `journalctl` might tell you more about what happens.